# How do I map to and from a complex type in EF4.3 code-first?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I've got a entity type like this:

```
public class Invoice{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public InvoiceNumberSequence Sequence { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

The `InvoiceNumberSequence` looks like this:

```
public class InvoiceNumberSequence { 
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string GetSequence() {
        return Prefix + Number;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I have an existing database that I cannot change and I'm trying to map tables/columns to my domain model. Here's how the table looks:

```
[SYSTEMINVOICES]
INVOICE_ID int
INV_TOTAL decimal
INVOICE_SEQ varchar(255)
```

I have a `DbContext` like this:

```
public MyDatabaseContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PredictedHeat>().ToTable("SYSTEMINVOICES");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("INVOICE_ID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Invoice>().Property(p => p.Amount).HasColumnName("INV_TOTAL");        
        //need something here to map my invoice sequence to my database table
    }
}
```

I need to map the InvoiceNumberSequence both directions... 1) from the database field to the InvoiceNumberSequence class, AND 2) from the InvoiceNumberSequence.GetSequence() method to the database field.

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to map the result from `GetSequence` with a database field? is that it? and I guess you want to store the result in the `INVOICE_SEQ` field right?

Comment: That's 1/2 of it. I also need to map from the database field to my object model as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So instead of `GetSequence` use a property:

```
public class InvoiceNumberSequence { 
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Sequence {
        get { retrun Prefix + Number; }
        set { // Add your parsing logic }
    }
}
```

And in mapping add:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<InvoiceNumberSequence>()
            .Property(p => p.Sequence)
            .HasColumnName("INVOICE_SEQ");
modelBuilder.ComplexType<InvoiceNumberSequence>()
            .Ignore(p => p.Prefix);
modelBuilder.ComplexType<InvoiceNumberSequence>()
            .Ignore(p => p.Number);
```