# Can I Embed an object in an EF entity (serialize on save, deserialize on access)?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class that I want to keep meta data for -- there a several interaction scenarios so meta allows me to keep different meta for different interaction types.

```
class Feed()
{
    Guid FeedId { get; set; }
    ObjectMetaDictionary Meta { get; set; }
}
```

I would like EF to serialize this ObjectMetaDictionary and store it as a string/VarChar in the database.  When I retrieve a record I want it to be deserialized as an ObjectMetaDictionary.

Does EF support this?  How can I do it?

I am using Entity Framework Code First.

**SOLVED:  I provided an answer below that solved my problem.  I will accept this answer as soon as SO allows me to.**

Comment: UPDATE:  I started using MongoDB shortly after writing this question.  With Mongo this question is not even relevant because it's so easy to do.  I loved EF when using SQL but I'd rather have Mongo any day of the week -- and based on 14 years experience I'd say mongo performs better for web/apps any day.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently this is actually quite easy.  I was able to get it working thanks to some help from this previous SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904298/how-do-i-map-to-and-from-a-complex-type-in-ef4-3-code-first).

Fluent configuration in `OnModelCreating` allows us to tell EF what to use as the value property for serializing to the DB and back out again.

Here's my solution:

```
public class Feed
{
    public virtual Guid FeedId { get; set; }

    public virtual FeedMetaData Meta { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

}

public class FeedMetaData
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

    public string Serialized
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data); }
        set
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return;

            var metaData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(value);

            Data = metaData ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
    }

    // addl code removed...
}

public class FeedsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<FeedMetaData>()
                    .Property(p => p.Serialized)
                    .HasColumnName("Meta");
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<FeedMetaData>().Ignore(p => p.Data);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a very slick piece of work, and a technique I've not found discussed elsewhere, and one I would not have easily worked out on my own. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Don't forget that EF (at least EF6) append "_Serialized" or whatever you called your property to the field your saving.  In the case of a DB first approach, this info might be useful

Comment: Or you can just put `[NotMapped]` on the Data property.

Comment: This marked the record as dirty, resulting in a db query. Any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: I wish I had seen this answer before I re-invented the wheel. My slightly different take a https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207034/492

Answer (score 1):

Have your Entity Framework object be simple and have a String property for the column in the database.

```
class Feed()
{
    Guid FeedId { get; set; }
    String Meta { get; set; }
}
```

Create methods that save and load the property as such:  (it's been a while since I've used EF, so i'm not sure if you can create a transient property with these getter/setters or if you need something else)

```
//Reading from string column Meta
(ObjectMetaDictionary) XamlServices.Load(new StringReader(someFeed.Meta));

//Saving to string column Meta
someFeed.Meta = XamlServices.Save(value);
```

This brings another whole issue to your project though.  Changing your `ObjectMetaDictionary` might cause it to not deserialize from the database correctly.  Your `ObjectMetaDictionary` becomes essentially part of your database schema and you will need to handle versioning or changes accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially how I have it now but this design is weak because it means I always have to have a superclass to handle the serialization/deserialization.  I'm looking to be able to use the Feed.Meta AS an ObjectMetaDictionary.

Comment: What kind of EF mapping are you doing, code first, edmx first, ...?

Comment: Code First, I updated the question to indicate this in case anyone misses the tags I set.

Answer (score 1):

The feature [HasConversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.hasconversion?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_PropertyBuilder_1_HasConversion__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func__0___0___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0__0___) saved my life. Unlock all json formats! Enjoy it!

```
public partial class Feed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //this column will be mapped to a "nvarchar(max)" column. perfect!
    public Dictionary<string, string> Meta { get; set; }
}

public class FeedsDbContext : DbContext
{

    public FeedsDbContext(DbContextOptions<FeedsDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Feed> Feed { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Feed>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(p => p.Meta).HasConversion(
                x => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x) //convert TO a json string
                , x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(x) //convert FROM a json string
            );
        });
    }

}
```