# Entity Framework code first: custom handling of a complex type (NameValueCollection)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

in my POCO entity I have a NameValueCollection property that I need to store in a column as a string and process to NameValueCollection on CRUD and vise versa.

Is Entity framework (current version 6) capable of doing that? if so where I can start.

Answer (score 0):

found it [Can I Embed an object in an EF entity (serialize on save, deserialize on access)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779740/can-i-embed-an-object-in-an-ef-entity-serialize-on-save-deserialize-on-access)

The best is to ignore the property of complex type:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<NameValueCollection>();
```

and introduce a new property to hold the serialized object.