# Collection does not appear in my database (code first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to add a list of actor name list to a film.

Cinema class :

```
public int Id{get;set;}
public double Price{get;set;}
public ICollection<string> ActorName {get;set;}
```

So the problem is that the table's ActorName doesn't appear. I only have the id and the price. I also try to make a class Actor and Cinema. But I have the same result.

---

Cinema:

```
public int Id{get;set;}
public double Price{get;set;}
public ICollection<Actor> Actor{get;set;}
```

Actor :

```
public Id{get;set;}
public Name{get;set;}
```

Comment: Checkout this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711986/entity-framework-code-first-cant-store-liststring

Comment: How would you expect the ActorName column to look like in the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Code First - Can't Store List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711986/entity-framework-code-first-cant-store-liststring)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto when I insert a list to ActorName I want see the list (collection) in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Change your collection like so:

```
  public ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
```

Make sure you have a class named Actor with the necessary properties (ID, ActorName, Price, etc...)

Another thing I just remembered...add a constructor to Cinema:

```
      Cinema:
      public int Id{get;set;}
      public double Price{get;set;}
      public ICollection<Actor> Actor{get;set;}

      public Cinema(){

         this.Actors = new List<Actor>();
      }
```

You can use any type of collection...List, IEnumerable, IQueryable, etc...

Eager Loading:

```
   _context.Cinema.Include("Actor").Where(c => c.ID == id && c.Actor.Any(a => a.ActorName == "Dick Richie")).ToList();
```

Comment: I already make this. I don't see the collection in ma table of cinema...

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled? If not, then you'll have to include the collection in your query to see the list.

Comment: What is the lazy loading ? How I disabled ?

Comment: It loads collections automatically which in my opinion you shouldn't do. Eager loading is the opposite. There are properties in VS you can check or just put a break point inside the DbContext constructor and then check the settings using "this": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;  What is Configuration ? it's not recognized.