# C# Entity Framework Json deserialize String array issues

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, deserialization

I have A Json file Which can be used for deserialize to Entity framework. For simplify we can assume the Json like this

```
{
  "stat": "val0",
  "results": [
    {
      "datasets": [
        "val1",
        "val2"
      ],
      "head": "val3"
    },
    {
      "datasets": [
        "val4",
        "val5"
      ],
      "head": "val6"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my Entity Classes like

```
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int stat { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<String> _strings { get; set; }
    public List<string> Strings
    {
        get { return _strings; }
        set { _strings = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public string datasets
    {
        get { return String.Join(",", _strings); }
        set { _strings = value.Split(',').ToList(); }
    }
    public string head{ get; set; }
    public virtual root { get; set; }

}
```

I know Entity Framework does not support primitive types and I know problem causes from my datasets fields. that I found this way to solve String array deserialize issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31648135/4239763). I have tried

```
 URL = "http://...";//Restful webservice address
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 String JSON= client.DownloadString(URL);
 var dsobj = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
```

But I got

> System.InvalidOperationException

Then I have decided to use Newtonsoft

```
URL = "http://...";//Restful webservice address
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String JSON= client.DownloadString(URL);
var dsobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Then I got this error

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'results[0].senses[0].definition', line 1, position...

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711986/entity-framework-code-first-cant-store-liststring) but I cant figure it out.

How can Fix these isseus. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The `datasets` JSON array should match the `List<string>` in Entity Class. Try `public List<string> dataSets` and `public string datasetsAsString`.

Comment: I Cannot understand @michaelyin Could you show me?

Answer (score 0):

Your json consist of two unwanted commas, try removing those

[image]

Comment: When I simplify the original json I forget clear that commas. Then I have editted the json.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string stat { get; set; } // changed to a string
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<String> _dataSets { get; set; }
    public List<string> dataSets // the JSON array will deserialize into this property
    {
        get { return _dataSets; }
        set { _dataSets = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public string DatasetsAsString
    {
        get { return String.Join(",", _dataSets); }
        set { _dataSets = value.Split(',').ToList(); }
    }
    public string head{ get; set; }
    public virtual root { get; set; }

}
```

Edit: stat property has to be a string too.