# How does List<> look like in db if its class filed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

For example, I use Entity Framework to create a database. I create a class and it has a List field. How will it look like in table?
If it is *int* field, it is gonna be a column with numbers (same with strings, booleans...), I get it. But what about lists?

Comment: When you create this in Entity Framework and allow it to generate the database, what happens?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @David nothing... I mean, it generates the database.

Comment: @SofiaBo: And when you look at the database, what do you find?  Currently you're asking what your code outputs.  So why not just look at the output?

Comment: Please show an example and reword your question. This is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I can tell from your question you're wondering what happens if you're creating a database with Entity Framework from an code-first approach, from an entity which contains a list as a property. 
Entity Framework doesn't save lists as columns in your table, instead it creates a relationship between the two types of entities. 
If you have a class "Bob" which contains a List of type , then a relationship will be established. 
If the data type is primitive, you could either create a new entity that stores the primitive datatype or do some sort of string processing as explained by the answer in this question: [EF can't store list string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711986/entity-framework-code-first-cant-store-liststring)

**EDIT:** Read more about relationship databases here on Entity Framework tutorial: [Configure one to many EF](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: @SofiaBo No problem, please mark as answer if it helped.