# InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Array' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: asp.net

I am making a Web API with .Net and it is receiving a custom JSON object from a web form to serialize to the model. I am currently having an issue displaying the API response. I am storing the data in an in memory database at first just to get it working.

I am not sure why it is asking me for a primary key despite there being a key defined on my model.

My next step is to add multipart-form data but that is its own can of worms.
The error happens on the `_context.ProjectItems.ToListAsync();` line.
I have already added an ID to the model.

```
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public new long Id { get; set; }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ProjectItem>> GetProjectItem(long id)
    {
        var projectItem = await _context.ProjectItems.FindAsync(id);

    if (projectItem == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }



    return projectItem;



   }
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProjectItem>>> 
GetProjectItems()
    {
        return await _context.ProjectItems.ToListAsync();
    }
```

My model: ProjectItem.cs

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace RupAPI.Controllers
    {
        public class ProjectItem : Project
        {
            [Required]
            [Key]
            public new long Id { get; set; }

            public string ProjName { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateSub { get; set; }
            public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
            public string Desc { get; set; }
            public Array Sku { get; set; }
            public Array SkuDesc { get; set; }
            public Array Item { get; set; }
            public Array ItemDesc { get; set; }
            public Array FileName { get; set; }
            public new byte[] File { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Array' requires a primary key to be defined.
>           Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model)
>           Stack Query Cookies Headers 
>           InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Array' requires a primary key to be defined.
>           +
>                       return await _context.ProjectItems.ToListAsync();
>           lambda_method(Closure , object )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconsider the usage of `Array` as type for your properties, which cause this issue.

If those properties are really more than just `string`, create additional model(s) to represent the properties and use [relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) to store them in your database.

If the properties are lists of strings, there are several solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711986/entity-framework-code-first-cant-store-liststring). If possible I would go for Sasan's solution, which is for your case to replace `Array` with `string[]` and add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectItem>()
    .Property(e => e.Sku)
    .HasConversion(
        v => string.Join(',', v),
        v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
// TODO: also to that for the other properties
```

to your database context's [OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/).

Comment: Ok, I see that Array causes the problem. Can you elaborate on the solution you offered or give any code examples? My JSON object is passing arrays of strings so I am at a loss with how to bind these to properties if I am not using the datatype Array.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I am not sure that is the direction I want to go with this. I upvoted your answer but it won't show cause I have no feedback score myself. I will see if anyone has an alternative. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! Alternatives would be to either serialize the string lists and store the result as string, or store the data in separate tables (thus models and relations).