# Save HashSet<string> in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This is my current EF Core model:

```
public class Application
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

The hashset property doesn't work on its own, so I've added this in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
     .Property(e => e.Fields)
     .HasConversion(
        v => v.ToArray(),
        v => new HashSet<string>(v));
```

That works in some cases, but there is a big issue with it.

When I insert an application initially, the hashset gets converted to a string array correctly, and the postgresql db driver stores it correctly.

However when I later get the application again, modify the hashset, and then call `.SaveChanges();` it does not work!

I have to explicitly call `ctx.Update(app);` for the changes to get saved.

I think that is because the `HashSet<string>` instance does not change, only its content changes, so the change tracker won't be able to see any changes (but maybe I'm wrong about that reasoning).

How can I fix this?

The example here only has one HashSet, but other models will have many more properties that will all suffer from the same problem.

- Is there any way to make the change tracker aware of those changes?
- Is there maybe a way to implement a custom collection of some sort that will notify its "container" that it has been modified?
- Is it maybe possible to tell EF to check the **value after the conversion**, instead of the hashset itself?

Comment: tried to use [`ObservableHashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.observablehashset-1?view=efcore-3.0) instead of plain `HashSet`..?

Comment: @BagusTesa Good idea! I replaced both occurrences of `HashSet<string>` (where the prop is declared and where the conversion happens), but unfortunately it didn't help. Still no automatic change detection.

Comment: Does it work if you use `List` instead of `HashSet`?

Comment: hi @Riki, just to be sure, you are not using `AsNoTracking` right? i do curious, why did microsoft said `ObservableHashSet` is a `HashSet` implemented that publish EF events but doesnt work in your case..

Comment: @mjwills Doesn't work with List either.

Comment: @BagusTesa Yeah, I'm not using AsNoTracking or similar anywhere in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712012/11649486

> Entity Framework does not support collections of primitive types. You can either create an entity (which will be saved to a different table) or do some string processing to save your list as a string and populate the list after the entity is materialized.

Comment: It is worth noting that EF is moving towards supporting collections of primitive types. It's worth checking if it's now available. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-preview-4/.

It also can be done via Value converters now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations