# How do I store a property of IEnumerable<string> in a Cosmos table, with EF Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

My project is using EF Core 3.1, and targeting Azure Cosmos as the database.

I have an entity like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Names {get;set;}
    ... other fields
}
```

That I would like to end up in a Cosmos document like this:

```
{
    "Names": ["Name1", "Name2"]
}
```

With the entity as is (`IEnumerable<string>`) I get the error:

> The property 'MyEntity.Names' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'IEnumerable' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type.

If I change the entity to:

```
public class NameEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class MyEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<NameEntity> Names {get;set;}
    ... other fields
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(e =>
    {
        e.OwnsMany(p => p.Identifiers);
    });
}
```

The document looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": "XXXXXX",
    "Names:" [
       {},
       {}
    ],
}
```

So I change the OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(e =>
    {
        e.OwnsMany(p => p.Identifiers, o=> o.HasKey(k=>k.Name));
    });
}
```

And I then get:

```
{
  "Names": [
    {
        "Name": "<string1>",
        "Id": "XXXX"
    },
    {
        "Identifier": "<string2>",
        "Id": "XXXX"
    }
]}
```

I've also looked at value converters, but I think that is more for converting property values between types, rather than converting an entity to a string.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would something like a List or Array not work for your situation. What's the idea behind the IEnumerable type

Comment: The idea is to make the json 'look nice'.  List and array are convertible it IEnumerable so not likely to work but will give it a try.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question to yours : [Entity Framework - Code First - Can't Store List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711986/entity-framework-code-first-cant-store-liststring)

Currently, it's not possible to store a list of primitive type (string included).

Your best bet would be to store the list as a string in your database, and when you fetch it you transform it back to a list.

As the link above explained it, you can do in your OnModelCreating method :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.Strings)
        .HasConversion(
            v => string.Join(',', v),
            v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: I was explicitly told not to create a CSV :-) 
I did come up with a solution that involved changes to the Cosmos driver.  I managed to get it working correctly for writes to Cosmos, but it was a bit hacky for reads.  If I managed to make reads nicer, I might submit it as a PR.

Comment: You could use a converter from IReadOnlyCollection<string> to string[], and it will work with CosmosDB provider, https://medium.com/@shahabganji/store-array-of-strings-with-ef-core-cosmosdb-8c69321b3983