# Configure EF Core with Cosmos DB to store ICollection of string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Entity framework has some nice documentation about [Embedding entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#embedded-entities) but I cannot figure out how to embed a simple string array `IEnumerable<string>`.

Sample class

```cs
public class Post {
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Content {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<string> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

This should be saved in cosmos as:

```json
{
  "id": "xxx",
  "content": "long content here",
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"],
  ...
}
```

I know I have to configure something in the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` of the Context. But I cannot get it setup correctly.

I've tried to following options (and several other `ToJsonProperty` methods):

- `modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().OwnsMany(p => p.Tags);`
- `modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().OwnsMany<string>(p => p.Tags);`

Eventually I want to be able to query based on those tags, any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557600/639153) but converting the array to a comma separated string would defeat the purpose (since that doesn't allow us to query those posts).

Someone else [asked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/152529/querying-tags-with-cosmos-db-with-ef-core.html?childToView=162091#answer-162091) roughly the same question on the Microsoft forums, where a Microsoft employee states that in pure CosmosDB it is possible to embed a string array in cosmos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14762) tracking this issue at the EF core provider for Cosmos.

So the **Official** answer is, this is currently **unsupported**. At least until the mentioned issue is closed.

Update, July 2021, it seems that this is now supported in EfCore 6.0.0

Answer (score 3):

I recently tried to find an answer to the same question. Did not find a good solution, so I created a new model

```
public class Tag
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
  ...
  public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

...
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().OwnsMany(p => p.Tags);
```

Comment: While this is a great way around the issue, the main issue is still that a simple string collection isn’t supported. Not sure what the best answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a value converter like this:

```cs
public class TagsValueConverter : ValueConverter<IReadOnlyCollection<string>, string[]>
{
    public TagsValueConverter() : base(
        value => value.ToArray(),
        dbValue => dbValue.ToList())
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do we use this ValueConverter? I think this wasn't available before and starting 6.0 your dont need custom things anymore since it's now build in? https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14762

Comment: The value converter I think was there even for ef core 3.1, but the issue is still there, I will open a new issue on the github since yesterday I had the issue with ef core 6.0.3
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/25344#issuecomment-1066466185

Answer (score -1):

In your model builder use a value converter like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().Property(p => p.Tags).HasConversion(v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v), v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(v));
```

Comment: This work-around is already mentioned in the answer that I'm referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557600/639153 and the problem is that you can then save the data, but you have no way to query based on that data, which is part of the question. example: Get posts that have tag x?

Comment: also you could use a converter from IReadOnlyCollection<string> to string[], and it will work with CosmosDB provider, https://medium.com/@shahabganji/store-array-of-strings-with-ef-core-cosmosdb-8c69321b3983