# EF Core 5.0 - How to seed entity with List<string> property in a migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

It makes a few hour that I'm trying to figure this one out, but could find a solution.

I have an entity with a `List<string>` property and I'd like to data seeding it. I succeeding using `modelBuilder.Entity<T>.HasData()`, but it doesn't work with `dotnet ef migrations`.

Here is my entity:

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my `DbContext.OnModelCreating` override:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
        .HasData(
            new MyEntity { Id = 1, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2" } },
            new MyEntity { Id = 2, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2", "text3" } },
            new MyEntity { Id = 3, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2" } },
            new MyEntity { Id = 4, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2" } },
            new MyEntity { Id = 5, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2", "text3" } });
}
```

This works if I run my app, it creates the table and seed it with the wanted values. But if I run `dotnet ef migrations add AddMyEntities --project src/MyProject --startup-project src/MyProject.Api`, I get this output:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.NotSupportedException: The type mapping for 'List<string>' has not implemented code literal generation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral(Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.UnknownLiteral(Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.Literal(Object[,] values)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(InsertDataOperation operation, IndentedStringBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(String builderName, IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IndentedStringBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateMigration(String migrationNamespace, String migrationName, IReadOnlyList`1 upOperations, IReadOnlyList`1 downOperations)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The type mapping for 'List<string>' has not implemented code literal generation.
```

How can I seed a simple `List<string>` property?

---

**Edit:** I think this question is different from other questions such as [Entity Framework - Code First - Can't Store List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712012/186861) because my program works fine if I launch it on a blank DB (using PostgreSQL, it creates a `Names` column of type `text[]`, as you would expect). The problem is when I use the `dotnet ef` migration tool.

Comment: Unless I missed some improvement to EF, entities can't have collections of simple types (int, string, etc). If I did miss an new update, I'd love to see how it stores that in the DB, someone point me to that.

Comment: Good answer with possible solutions below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712012/186861

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework - Code First - Can't Store List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711986/entity-framework-code-first-cant-store-liststring)

Comment: This is not exactly the same, the code in my question works if I run on a blank DB (the column type is `text[]`), it's only the migration tool that doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like something that's not supported by EF + Postgresql. Seeding properties like this is somewhere in-between scalar properties (supported by EF) and navigation properties (not supported). Not sure if EF's seeding code has handles to let data providers add supported data types.

Comment: See this ticket on the dotConnect for PostgreSQL forum, it's on their roadmap: https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44479&sid=147a706e6deeca8bb59c2c4c61317052

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** the OP mentions that it's using PostgreSQL with the corresponding EF provider, so the problem is not a missing value converter.

The issue seems to be related to a limitation in EF Core itself. The migration scaffolding process currently uses a built-in, hardcoded [CSharpHelper](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/1d9589691029d1a1b33aeb4e90eb846cddd4382f/src/EFCore.Design/Design/Internal/CSharpHelper.cs) class which knows how to generate C# literals for a closed set of types. For example, it knows how to generate `object[]` literals, but not `IEnumerable<>`. (Ref.: [dotnet/efcore#12979](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12979#issue-349796990)). It seems that now it's possible for providers to add generation for code literals for other types, and I could found that it was added for some types in [npgsql/efcore.pg#0deb6a23](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/commit/0deb6a23a1eb2c51ed74aa10a8997e1f2885e18e), but not for `List<>` as far as I understsand... but I can be wrong since I haven't tested any of this myself.

My suggestion? Either use `string[]` or ditch `HasData` and provide some custom seeding logic.

---

**OLD:** The problem is not with the `HasData` functionality itself. The underlying problem is that EF Core does not natively know how to store a `List<string>` into the database, thus it fails.

What you can do is to define a custom `ValueConverter` that instructs EF Core how to store that specific property into your database column (You can check [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#the-valueconverter-class) about this topic).

Probably the best way to go would be define this conversion using [Newtonsoft JSONConvert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
        .Property(p => p.Names)
        .HasConversion(
            listOfStringNames => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfStringNames),
            namesJsonRepresentation => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(namesJsonRepresentation));
        .HasData(
            new MyEntity { Id = 1, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2" } },
            new MyEntity { Id = 2, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2", "text3" } },
            new MyEntity { Id = 3, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2" } },
            new MyEntity { Id = 4, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2" } },
            new MyEntity { Id = 5, Names = new List<string> { "text1", "text2", "text3" } });
}
```

As a side note, I would like to mention that even though `HasData` is nice, in my personal experience was better to just write my own `DatabaseInitializer` class that would seed the data I need with any custom logic I want, without any of the limitations that `HasData` has (Ref.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#limitations-of-model-seed-data)

Comment: I did try that, but then the column type becomes `text`, while if I don't add a converter, the column type is `text[]` (as expected). The peculiar thing about this problem is that it works if I run it on a blank DB, it's only the dotnet EF migration tool that does not work.

Comment: @Creak what DB are you using? AFAIK, no SQL provider has support for storing an array of strings (text[]), therefore you have to store them as a single string using some sort of delimiter, or serialized as JSON. Also, how do you know it works on an empty database? If you can't apply the migration you won't be able to find out

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL... That may be why it works when I run the program but not when I do the migration with dotnet ef. I guess dotnet ef doesn't check the DB provider?

Comment: @Creak hmm just found out that PosgreSQL has support for array data types It seems that you have it properly configured according to https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html . Have you double checked that you are using the NpgSQL provider for EFCore, and not the SQL Server one , right?

Comment: @Creak which version of npsql provider are you using? You might want to try defining your property in the Entity as `string[]` instead of `List<string>`, after reading through some issues it seemed that worked in some cases

Comment: For the provider, I got Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 5.0.2.

Comment: @Creak could you post the whole code for you DbContext configuration? Including the part where you setup the provider

Comment: Here's my DbContext and the class extension I use to configure it: https://gist.github.com/MightyCreak/5dd1afefb6a94057630fc1a717b1136f