# Persisting and retrieving serialized entity property with Entity Framework 6.1 code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1, entity-framework-migrations

Example: Let's say I have these three classes. `Foo` is a proper Entity Framework entity with a DbSet whereas I want my EF DbContext to be unaware of `Bar` and `Baz` because I have flagged Foo's Bar property with my made up `SerializedColumn` attribute. By applying that attribute, I want EF to serialize the instance of Bar with its Bazes into a single string field, and transparently deserialize Bar to a Bar object when a Foo is materialized by EF.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [SerializedColumn]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    // ..
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Baz[] Baz { get; set; }
    // ..
}

public class Baz
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ..
}
```

So Foo's table columns would look like:

```
[Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
[Bar] [nvarchar](max) NULL
```

And when I query a `Foo` I get back one with the `Bar` property already deserialized. When I insert or update a `Foo` the `Bar` property gets serialized by EF without me having to think about it. The only thing I have to do is add the `[SerializeColumn]` attribute to properties.

Goals:

- I'm not necessarily looking for a full blown solution (although I would accept it) but for guidance on where to jump into EF's pipeline, and how to do that. I.E. what EF classes, configurations, conventions, etc. do I need to take into account?
- I want Migrations to be generated as one would expect. Which is to say, I wouldn't want my `Bar` property to turn into a "Bar_Id" field that points to a "Bar" table. Instead I want a `nvarchar(max)` "Bar" field that will contain the serialized version of a `Bar` object. If this simply isn't possible, please say so in your answer.

Notes:

- The idea for this came after watching the [Building Applications with Entity Framework 6](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417) video by Rowan Miller.
- `ComplexType` does not serve my needs. I need deep serialization and do not need to be able to filter or sort on any properties of what has been serialized.
- I plan on serializing with Newtonsoft's JSON library, but how serialization happens doesn't really matter.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779740/can-i-embed-an-object-in-an-ef-entity-serialize-on-save-deserialize-on-access

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey I've done that in the past and it works, but am looking to make persistence totally transparent. That is only one property `Bar` with my made up `SerializeColumnAttribute`, and no `BarSerialized` property.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible in EF6. What you really need is a customer type converter. That feature is [planned](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/242) for EF7 but not yet implemented.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only solution is this,

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // Not Mapped attribute will make EF
    // ignore this property completely
    [NotMapped]
    public Bar BarObject { 
      get;
      set;
    }

    public string Bar{
       get{
          return JsonConvert.Serialize(BarObject);
       }
       set{
          BarObject = JsonConvert.Deserialize<BarObject>(value);
       }
    }
}
```

Updated as per suggestion by @zds

Comment: Thank you Akash but I gave the bounty to @bubi since he answered first with essentially the same answer as you, albeit a little less detailed. If I could, I would have split the bounty between both answers.

Comment: Could it be better to move serialization logic to 'public string Bar' property. Not to serialize and deserialize all the time, when changing something. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No way to do it without modifing EF.
With EF 6 I think that several people did it with a text backing field and some limitations (Bar and Bar children does not access to EF persisted property or you need other work after deserialization).

Comment: I'd be just fine with the limitations that come with a text backing field in the database (no filtering, in-database projections, etc.). Or by text backing field are you referring to using two properties, one marked [NotMapped] that is the in-memory, decrypted version of the encrypted property that EF will persist?

Comment: For backing field I mean two properties, one marked [NotMapped] that is the in-memory, decrypted version of the encrypted property that EF will persist.

Comment: Well, nothing wrong with backing properties if that's what it comes to. Thanks @bubi I'm going to let this bounty linger for a bit longer to see if anyone else can add some helpful information.