# EntityFramework and writing 3rd party types to DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to write a class to the database using entityframework.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Key]
    public long ID {get; set;}

    public Type MyType {get;set;}
}
```

My `DbContext` contains a `DbSet` of MyClass, but when I try to create the DB,
I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type
>   'CustomAttributeData' requires a primary key to be defined.'

I'm guessing it's because EF is trying to use the inner structure of `System.Type`.

Is there a way to make EF write this field (or any other classes we can't change) to the DB?

Comment: But how it is supposed to be serialized to the DB ? What kind of field this is supposed to be in your DB ?

Comment: @Pac0: binary format.

Comment: May I ask what is your goal with this ? What functionality are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Pac0: I don't know what other properties will be added to the class. I'd like not to serialize each property to JSON like this.

Answer (score 1):

Why serializing the type itself? I think that storing its full name should be enough:

Ignore `MyType` property using [NotMapped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14785553/2780791) attribute and serialize the type name instead the type itself (`MyType.FullName`) and create it back using `Type.GetType()`.

Note: for complex custom types, an elegant solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14785553/2780791).

**[Edit]** Since `Type` actually may be a custom complex type, a possible solution is using [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) and [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) to obtain regular strings that can be directly stored into the database.

Comment: ok, but it's not only that property. There will be other "complex" properties. (BTW - Type is not that object's type... its something else)

Comment: @Idov - then take a look upon the suggested solution which basically uses Json.NET to serialize and deserialize complex objects to and from a string representation. You should also replace `Type` (aka. System.Type) with `CustomType` or something similar to avoid confusion.